# What is wrong with this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, query-tuning

I need to do tuning on this sp:

```
alter PROCEDURE Gaming.usp_DB_GetGameResultsByDateTime 
(@FromDateTime AS DATETIME2(7) = null ,
 @ToDateTime AS DATETIME2(7)   = null)
AS
   DECLARE @FromDateTime_Actual AS DATETIME2(7) , 
           @ToDateTime_Actual AS DATETIME2(7); 
   SET @FromDateTime_Actual = ISNULL(@FromDateTime, DATEADD (DAY, -1, SYSDATETIME()));
   SET @ToDateTime_Actual = ISNULL (@ToDateTime , SYSDATETIME ());

   SELECT  Id, GameTypeId, PlayerId,
           BetAmount, Profit, 
           DateAndTime
   FROM Gaming.GameResults
   WHERE DateAndTime >= @FromDateTime_Actual
     AND DateAndTime < @ToDateTime_Actual
   ORDER BY DateAndTime ASC;
GO
```

What is wrong with this stored procedure? How would you rewrite this stored procedure?

Comment: What issues are you having with it?  It seems simple enough.  If it's performance, make sure you have indexes on the DateAndTime column...

Comment: What issues are you having that require tuning?

Comment: hi, i had index on the dateandtime. i thoght mayby the sp recompile in evrey run becuase how it worte ? somebody think like me ?

Comment: Why did you think that? It doesn't change `SET` options or have any DDL statements?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with this stored procedure.

You could make it a little bit more readable by getting rid of the variables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
        Gaming.usp_DB_GetGameResultsByDateTime
        (
        @FromDateTime AS DATETIME2(7) = NULL ,
        @ToDateTime AS DATETIME2(7) = NULL
        )
AS
DECLARE
        SELECT  Id, GameTypeId, PlayerId, BetAmount, Profit, DateAndTime
        FROM    Gaming.GameResults
        WHERE   DateAndTime >= ISNULL (@FromDateTime , DATEADD (DAY , -1 , SYSDATETIME ()))
                AND DateAndTime < ISNULL (@ToDateTime , SYSDATETIME ())
        ORDER BY
                DateAndTime ASC
GO
```

and more efficient by creating an index on `GameResults (DateAndTime)`

Comment: ok, but in this way is saving costs of recompilation for a query also if it run with differential params ? or there way to save the execution plan for all runs ?

Comment: @dani: `SQL Server` will cache the execution plan for the procedure unless it's declared with `WITH RECOMPILE`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, the proc is fairly simple.  If you have performance issues, make sure you have an index on `DateAndTime` since all your filtering is on that field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks goods to me except I might do

```
WHERE DateAndTime between @FromDateTime_Actual AND @ToDateTime_Actual
```

but I wouldn't expect it to affect performance

If you're looking to make performance faster you should probably consider looking at your indexes for example DateAndTime might be a good place to start.

After that you'll need to look at Perforamnce Tips articles [like this one](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1466951/SQL-Server-Performance-Tuning-for-SQL-Server-Developers.htm)

As Quassnoi noted, `BETWEEN` is inclusive which changes < @FromDateTime_Actual  to <= @FromDateTime_Actual. If you really want it to be not inclusive and you want to you `BETWEEN` you can modify the how you set @ToDateTime_Actual to make this happen.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive while the @op's query is not.

Comment: You also don't get index benefits of using `BETWEEN`

Comment: @Nai: this is news to me. Care to cite a source

Comment: @Nai - Nonsense. The parser just replaces it with `>=` and `<=` anyway. Try `select * from master..spt_values where number between 1 and 10` and look at the text shown in the actual execution plan.

Comment: @Martin @Conrad sorry my bad. ignore my previous comment. i got mixed up with not getting the index benefits if the where clause was constructed using a datediff function.